# How to convert country code from iso3 to iso2 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, country-codes

I have iso3 country code which I need to convert to iso2 in JavaScript or JQuery. For Example: USA to US.

I tried to use the Intl.Locale object, but this does not provide the needed information. Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: You've to use a conversion table.

Comment: Do you know an existing one that can be used?

Comment: Google knows ...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/maephisto/9228207?permalink_comment_id=1963107#gistcomment-1963107

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function convertISO3toISO2(iso3Code) {
  const isoCodes = {
    'AFG': 'AF',
    'ALA': 'AX',
    'ALB': 'AL',
    'USA': 'US',
    // ... Add more country mappings as needed
  };

  // Convert ISO3 code to uppercase for case-insensitivity
  const uppercaseISO3 = iso3Code.toUpperCase();

  // Check if the provided ISO3 code exists in the mapping
  if (isoCodes.hasOwnProperty(uppercaseISO3)) {
    return isoCodes[uppercaseISO3];
  } else {
    // Return null or handle the case where the ISO3 code is not found
    console.error('ISO3 code not found:', uppercaseISO3);
    return null;
  }
}

// Example usage:
const iso2Code = convertISO3toISO2('USA');
console.log(iso2Code); // Output: 'US'
```

```html
To convert a country code from ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 (ISO3) to ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 (ISO2) in JavaScript, you can use a mapping object that relates ISO3 codes to ISO2 codes. Here's an example function to perform this conversion:

For more country mapping as needed please visit below github url:

https://github.com/vtex/country-iso-3-to-2/blob/master/index.js
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Comment: "Add more country mappings as needed" sounds strange